# How to show android status bar without touch screen?

Tags: android

Is there any `shortcut key` to `drop down` the Android status bar without using the touch screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a device with a hardware keyboard:
In the launcher app (= homescreen): `Menu Key, then N`.

To close the status drawer again use the back button.